# Way to access variables of class from collection of its super?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

Suppose I have:

```
class Card{ }

class CardUnit extends Card {
  int attack = 4;
}

ArrayList<Card> listCards;
```

Is there any way to put both Cards and CardUnits in my listCards array and still be able to access the attack variable of the CardUnits that are in the list?  Or must I put the variable in the Card class too?

Comment: Your `Card` instance does not define any `attack` , so how do you expect to access this in such an instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all Cards have an attack, you can add an abstract getAttack() to the superclass.

```
class Card {
  public abstract int getAttack();
}
```

Otherwise, you could have an interface IAttackCard with a method getAttack(), that CardUnit implements. Then, when accessing cards from the list, you can check whether they're instances of IAttackCard.

```
   interface ICardAttack {
      public int getAttack();
   }

   class CardUnit extends Card implements ICardAttack {
      private int attack; 
      @Override
      public int getAttack() { return attack; }
    }
```

Testing directly for CardUnit with instanceof would interfere with the open-closed principle -- adding a new subclass of Card could require modification of existing code that works with Cards.

Comment: Thanks (everyone) for the quick input.  I like this idea in particular, I think it is just what I need for my situation.

Comment: @Robert - You're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. As the person asking the question, you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark. In any questions, you can vote for an answer by clicking the upward-pointing triangle -- or against with the downward-pointing triangle. There's more detail in the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Comment: I agree that using an interface is better than using instanceof, I tend to not add interfaces until the 2nd instance appears of a new sub-class, otherwise I have single use interfaces floating around everywhere.

That said, you could take this a step further and create just a more generic `IAttack` interface which simply means the class can Attack.  So if, in the future, you have `Dice` that can attack, you already have the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome mat.  I gave your answer the check, but I don't have enough 'rep' to vote up any responses.  I am new to java and just started using interfaces, so I'm still learning all the wonderful uses!

Comment: @Snekse - Preferring to refer to an object by an interface rather than a class can make code more extensible and more easily unit-tested. For me, these benefits have proven more valuable than the minimal cost of having  an interface with (so far) a single implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a method getAttack() in the Card class (with a default value) and override it in CardUnit you can access it.

Maybe you want to make the Card class abstract (you can't create objects); you can make the getAttack() method abstract and force subclasses to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `instanceof` to test for `CardUnit`, then act if true.

```
for (Card i : list) {
  if (i instanceof CardUnit){
    actOnAttackValue( (CardUnit) i );
  }
}
```

I'm not a fan of adding an abstract method to Card because

- You never said it was an abstract class. You may be instantiating it
- It doesn't make sense in other context.  Like adding a `gaveBirth()` method to a `Human` class